# How to put your android application on Android Market for free?

Tags: android, google-play

I am very new to the Android Market. I want to put my application up for free.

Is there any possibility for free "upload" (I saw you must pay 25$). This is for school project and I will not pay that money, too much for me `:D`

If there is no possibility for that, if there is someone out there with account, that I will send app to him and he will put it on Android Market.

Answer (score 10):

No that is not possible, if you want to publish on Google Play you have to get that Publisher Account which costs 25$. This fee is mainly to prevent people from spamming the market.

Alternatively you could look at publishing your application on other non-official "markets", most of them will let you do so for free. You will not get as much exposure, but if you're seeking a free way to get your application out there, that's the only way I know of doing so.

Comment: Yes, try Amazon, AppBrain, or just email the APK to your friends and have them install it manually, or host the APK file on a website and send the link for people to install manually (but they have to click that special check box - which you'll show them how).